# Yet another implementation of Conway's Game of life in Haskell

Tags: haskell, game-of-life

(Sorry for my bad English)
Hi, I'm interested in getting feedback of my own implementation of Conway's Game of Life.

Some details:

- Uses [gloss](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss) for animation
- Uses [rio](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rio) for shorter dependency list

My implementation suffers from performance issue when the population grows larger than 2000 cells.

My code:

- Main.hs:

```hs
module Main where

import           Lib
import qualified RIO.ByteString                as B
import           System.Environment
import qualified Graphics.Gloss                as G

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [file]      <- getArgs
  initialGrid <- B.readFile file
  let patt = parse initialGrid
  G.simulate G.FullScreen G.white 20 patt golPic (\_ _ ps -> eval ps)

golPic :: [Point] -> G.Picture
golPic ps =
  G.pictures [ G.translate (fromIntegral x * dIMENSION) (fromIntegral y * dIMENSION) (G.color G.black (G.rectangleSolid dIMENSION dIMENSION)) | (x, y) <- ps ]

parse :: B.ByteString -> [Point]
parse bs = map fst . filter ((== 42) . snd) . concatMap (\(x', xs) -> [ ((y', -x'), c) | (y', c) <- zip [1 .. length xs] xs ]) $ zip [1 .. length bs'] bs'
  where bs' = map B.unpack $! B.split 10 bs

dIMENSION :: Float
dIMENSION = 10
```

- Lib.hs:

```hs
module Lib where

import qualified RIO.Map                       as M

type Point = (Int, Int)

adjacents :: Point -> [(Point, Int)]
adjacents (x, y) = [ ((x + m, y + n), 1) | m <- [-1, 0, 1], n <- [-1, 0, 1], (m, n) /= (0, 0) ]

eval :: [Point] -> [Point]
eval cs =
  [ x
  | (x, y) <- M.toList . M.fromListWith (+) . concatMap adjacents $ cs
  , case y of
    2 -> x `elem` cs
    3 -> True
    _ -> False
  ]
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Maybe Point can be a data type?

Comment: @Evgeny also make the fields strict and unpack them `data Point = Point {-# UNPACK #-} !Int {-# UNPACK #-} !Int` https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#unpack-pragma

Comment: @DanielDíazCarrete - `{-# UNPACK #-}` is quite deep int optimisation that I know little about, thank you for the link!

Comment: Many unpacking here: https://github.com/simonmar/parconc-examples/blob/master/kmeans/KMeansCore.hs